# How to code a controller to store image webpaths in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I need to use MVC C# to create a method inside to store my QRCode webpath inside the database after the QRCode is generated, but I have no idea how to code it.

**Below is my code for the controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Generate(QRCodeModel qrcode)
    {
        try
        {

            qrcode.QRCodeImagePath = GenerateQRCode($"{ qrcode.QRCodeText}", $"http://sradmindashboardyumeng.azurewebsites.net/{qrcode.QRCodeText}");
            ViewBag.Message = "QR Code Created successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return View(qrcode);
    }


    public string GenerateQRCode(string qrcodeText, string qrcodeUrl)
    {
        string folderPath = $"~/assets/images/QRcode/";
        //string webPath = $"~/assets/images/QRcode/{qrcodeText}.jpg";
        string imagePath = $"~/assets/images/QRcode/{qrcodeText}.jpg";


        var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
        barcodeWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        var result = barcodeWriter.Write(qrcodeUrl);
        string barcodePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imagePath);
        var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(barcodePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                barcodeBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
        return imagePath;
    }



}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Your question is very vague since there can be different databases and different approach on how to do so. I suggest studying how to access the database in C# first then you could ask again for something more specific.

Comment: Can you please reformat your code properly?